# Query SQLAlchemy taking too long

Tags: python, mysql, performance, sqlalchemy

folks. I got a query on SQLalchemy that is taking too long. I don't if it's because the db is too big (6.5 millions of rows, so I don't think so)or if I'm doing something wrong. The following are the tables.

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    
    a = Column(CHAR(3))
    b = Column(DATE)
    c = Column(Integer)
    d = Column(Integer)
    e = Column(Integer)
    

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_b'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    a = Column(Integer)
    b  = Column(DATE)
    c  = Column(Integer)
    d  = Column(Integer)
```

And this is the query:

```
row  = session.query(A).get(id)

value = session.query(B.d).filter((B.b == row.b)&
                                  (B.d == row.c)&
                                  (B.e == row.d)).first()
```

With just one condition `B.b == row.b` it takes 2 minutes, with more I didn't saw it end after 10 minutes. It takes 0.5 seconds to get the `row` value. One thing that I saw was that indexing columns you intend to use the where clause one speed up things. If so, can I do it after I uploaded the records to my db?

Comment: Yes, indexes can be added afterwards. However, the changes won't be seen in the db itself unless you apply a migration or add the indexes yourself. SQLAlchemy won't automagically add them for you. And yes, missing indexes is the reason why your query is slow. An index on (b, d, e) for the B table will probably make it resolve in less than a tenth of a second. Alembic is what's usually used for migrations in SQLAlchemy: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ - you can add the indexes manually through MySQL console (`CREATE INDEX ..`): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Comment: @MatsLindh nailed it. But I was able to change put `b = Column(DATE,index=True)`  and the same for the other columns and it's working fine now (6 seconds). I didn't have to migrate nor do anything else.

Comment: @Rafael `EXPLAIN ... ` in front of the query that SQLAlchemy generates will also give you a lot of information about how you can optimize your query. You should be able to do this way faster than six seconds (depending on the number of rows returned), but if it's good enough, it's good enough. :-)